# Create groups of sub-matrices according to one column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like to know how to create groups of matrices starting from a Matrix in Matlab.

I have this Matrix :

```
A= [  1     1     2
     1     2     3
     1     3     4
     2     1     3
     2     2     4
     2     3     5
     3     1     4
     3     2     5
     3     3     6]
```

Now I would like to create several new matrices in which the elements, of each new matrix, are the first two columns of each row in A that have the third column of A in common.

For this case will be :

```
Af1=[1 1] % elements in common '2' (third column of A)
Af2= [1 2
      2 1] % elements in common '3' (third column of A)
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one approach with [`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) & [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) -

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(A(:,3),'rows','stable')
out  = arrayfun(@(n) A(idx==n,1:2),1:max(idx),'Uni',0)
```

Verify output with [`celldisp`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html) -

```
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     1     1
out{2} =
     1     2
     2     1
out{3} =
     1     3
     2     2
     3     1
out{4} =
     2     3
     3     2
out{5} =
     3     3
```

Or if you already know how many groups you would have and would like to save each such cell as a new matrix with names `Af1`, `Af2`, etc., you can use [`deal`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) (distribute inputs to outputs) -

```
>> [Af1,Af2,Af3,Af4,Af5] = deal(out{:})
Af1 =
     1     1
Af2 =
     1     2
     2     1
Af3 =
     1     3
     2     2
     3     1
Af4 =
     2     3
     3     2
Af5 =
     3     3
```

Comment: Perfect, just the last question. Now, If I have the generic Matrix A with unknown number of rows and columns (always knowing the column used to classify the others)? how could became the last approach? (e.g. generic example for undeterminable number of future matrices)

Comment: @ftrash but if you don't know the number of future matrices, how are you planning to use these variables then? A cell array or struct is really the best option.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for [**accumarray**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[ofGroup,~,subs] = unique(A(:,3));
values  = accumarray(subs,1:size(A,1),[],@(x) {A(x,[1,2])});

out = [ofGroup values]
```

[image]

For accessing the result you could use the [approach proposed by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29628552/2605073) using `deal`. But I'd rather rethink and use the cell array `out` directly:

```
>> out{3,2}

ans =

     1     3
     2     2
     3     1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but from Matlab the 'out' in workspace id just visible, while I need to operate with the matrices obtained from the above processes. How can i do?

Comment: isn't `ofgroup` just the first ouput from `unique`?

Comment: @Dan well observed! thanks. It just won't work if the order is important and one needed to use `unique(A(:,3),'stable')` as `accumarray` is not stable.

Comment: `accumarray` definitely looks elegant for this problem!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach:

```
B = sortrows(A, size(A,2)); %// sort rows acording to last column
gs = diff(find(diff([inf; B(:,3); inf])~=0)); %// sizes of groups determined by last col
result = mat2cell(B(:,1:end-1), gs); %// split according to those group sizes
```

Comment: very interesting approach! Wonder if it would be fasten than accumarray?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Who knows... Anyway, `accumarray` is the perfect suit for this problem. It's just that you guys picked it earlier! :-)